# Angular 2 custom validator with parameters

Tags: validation, parameters, angular

How do I create let's say my own maxLength validator in Angular 2?
All examples I could find use validators similar to 'required' one meaning that they already know the rules. They only accept one param - the control itself. How do I pass more parameters?

Here's the sample validator I have. How do I modify it to pass number 5 as a parameter?

```
export class MyValidators {
    static minValue(control:Control): {[s: string]: boolean} {
        var num = +control.value;
        if (isNaN(num) || num < 5 ) { return {"minValue": true}; }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is a sample. It's a min value validator where you pass in a number to validate.

```
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';

export const minValueValidator = (min:number) => {
  return (control:Control) => {
    var num = +control.value;
    if(isNaN(num) || num < min){
      return {
         minValue: {valid: false}
      };
    }
    return null;
  };
};
```

More details can be found in the [Custom Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) official documentation page.

Comment: `minValueValidator = (min: number) => {}` would be better ?!

Comment: That works. Thank you!
I also added isNaN check and replaced 'export const' with 'static' to make it a member of a class.

Comment: Updated to include NAN check

Comment: how can i pass variable value to this validator ? i notice it always expects string constant like <elem minValueValidator="5"> and won't let me do <elem minValueValidator={{a}}>

Comment: This won't work with the AOT compiler since lambda isn't supported: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Answer (score 4):

The minValueValidator example basically shows that you can use a factory for your custom validator so it will be something like this:

```
static minValue = (num: Number) => {
    return (control:Control) => {
         var num = control.value;
         if (isNaN(num) || num < 5 ) { return {"minValue": true}; }
         return null;
    }
}
```

In my case I use *FormControl* not *Control*

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution here that uses a little more Angular nuance:

```
  static minValue(min: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (control.value == null || control.value == '') {
        //avoid validation if empty, we are not testing for required here
        return null;
      }
      const errors: ValidationErrors = {};
      let num = +control.value;
      if (isNaN(num) || num < min) {
        errors.isLessThanMin = {
          message: `Number must be greater that ${min}`
        };
      }
      return Object.keys(errors).length ? errors : null;
    };
  }
```

Now you have a much more reusable html error message

```
<div *ngIf="control.errors.isLessThanMin>{{control.errors.isLessThanMin.message}}</div>
```