# Angular 2 - Validate that a form's value has changed from its default value with custom Validators

Tags: angular

My form is prefilled with `user.email`. I wish to only enable the edit button if the user fills the `FormControl`'s field with a value other than the original `user.email`. Is it possible to do this with a custom Validator?

This is my validator:

```
import { FormControl } from  '@angular/forms';

export class ChangedValidator {
   static isValid(control: FormControl): any {
     let initialValue = (' ' + control.value).slice(1);

     if(initialValue === control.value){
            return {
                "changed": true
            };
        }
      return null;
   }
}
```

The intention was to clone the `FormControl.value`, but I realize that this class is instantiated every time a value is changed in the FormControl.

One very hacky approach, that writes unreusable code is to fetch `user.email` from the data `provider` that stores it, and use it to compare it with the `FormControl.value`. As you may guess, the validator will ONLY work for the `User` object's parameters, and nothing else.

I want to write a universal `Validator` that checks if the form's current value is different from the value that was initialized.

**Edit:**

This is a way to do it with `pristine`, but it's not perfect.

```
import { FormControl } from  '@angular/forms';

export class ChangedValidator { 
   static isValid(control: FormControl): any {

     if(control.pristine){
            return {
                "unchanged": true
            };
        }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: If `pristine` isn't good enough (checks if the value changed, not if it changed and reverted to original), then, yes, you could do a custom validator where you send in the initial value as a parameter.

Comment: @silentsod `pristine` is probably "good enough", but if possible can you show me how to send it in? I looked at the other thread, but none of those solutions worked for me when I tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check that things have changed from the initial value and not just that the control is no longer pristine; as in, it could return to its initial value and you don't want the error, then you can implement a validation function as follows:

```
static isValid = (initialValue: any): any => {
  return(control: FormControl) => {
   console.log(control.value);

     if(JSON.stringify(initialValue) !== JSON.stringify(control.value)) {
       return {
              "changed": true
          };
     }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Note that is a [quick and dirty object check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) and that there was already an answer on [custom validators with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756159/angular-2-custom-validator-with-parameters) and an explanation of the [custom validation as a function factory](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation) but that's a little thin on details.

> The forbiddenNamevalidator factory returns the configured validator
>   function. That function takes an Angular control object and returns
>   either null if the control value is valid or a validation error
>   object. The validation error object typically has a property whose
>   name is the validation key ('forbiddenName') and whose value is an
>   arbitrary dictionary of values that we could insert into an error
>   message ({name}).

Here's a [playground](http://plnkr.co/edit/aG3pUtZArEom28VhrbZf?p=preview)

Comment: The playground doesn't work anymore, the preview loads for life. I've tested the way you do, control.value and initialValue will have ever the same value.