# How to pass another value to form validation method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created the form group as below

```
import { setPwd } from './validators';

@Component({
....
export class pwdComp {
     ...

     this.userFormPassword = this.fb.group({
       'password': ['', [ setPwd ]]
     });
```

In my another ts file has the `setPwd` method

```
export function setPwd(c: FormControl) {
  const SINGLE_LETTER_NUMERAL = /^\=\?$/;
  return SINGLE_LETTER_NUMERAL.test(c.value) ? null : {
    pwd: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}
```

The above script is working fine. But now my new scenario is I want to pass the pattern attribute to the `setPwd` method, So I tried as below

```
this.userFormPassword = this.fb.group({
    'password': ['', [ setPwd('**') ]]
});
```

and the `setPwd` method is

```
export function setPwd(c: FormControl, newPattern) {
```

But it is throwing the error. How to pass the extra value to the external function.

Comment: reference article : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular

Comment: or duplication of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756159/angular-2-custom-validator-with-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your function like below

```
export function setPwd(pattern: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = pattern.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'pwd': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}

this.userFormPassword = this.fb.group({
    'password': ['', setPwd('**') ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting `cannot read property 'controls' of undefined`  error.

Comment: is it conrols of undefined or control of undefined?

Comment: have you imported ValidatorFn and AbstractControl from angular ?